# How to specify a field, so that when we query, using Joda LocalDate or LocalDateTime value for the field, it is mapped to same column?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a postgres database that has a table `"draft"` containing a column set_up_time, saved as a timestamp:

```
@Column(nullable = false)
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
LocalDateTime setUpTime;
```

For certain reasons I need to keep this structure as it is. However I am expecting database queries `searching for records, for setUpTime as LocalDateTime and setUpTime as LocalDate`. How can I map it in a way, that hibernate queries the database with both these types for setUpTime, and returns the results accordingly?

The schema I am using is :

```
"create table draft (dtype varchar(31) not null, id int8 not null, creation_time timestamp not null, cust_ord varchar(1), description varchar(255), amount decimal(12, 2), user varchar(6), txn_time timestamp, text1from varchar(36), text2from varchar(36), text3from varchar(36), primary key (id))"
```

Comment: I assume you do store time information; or do you merely store the date part (meaning you set time values explicitly to 0)?
Can you specify the expected behaviour in case someone searches with a `LocalDate`?

Comment: Yes, I do store time information always.
However, if someone searches with a date only, I should return them all the records matching the given date in their datetime field, no matter what the time stamp on them is.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is write your queries like this:

```
public void findDrafts(LocalDate targetDate) {
    final Query query = entityManager.createQuery(
      "from Draft where setUpTime => :beginOfDay and setUpTime < :beginOfNextDay");
    query.setParameter("beginOfDay", targetDate.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().toLocalDateTime());
    query.setParameter("beginOfNextDay", targetDate.plusDays(1).toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().toLocalDateTime());
    return query.getResultList();
}
```